# Issue with CORS on Node.js on HTTPS (Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node.js API that I've deployed with Elastic Beanstalk, and when I send an POST request to the API over HTTP, I have no problem getting a response. However, when I try to send a POST request to the HTTPS listener for the API from a site that's served over HTTPS, I am getting the following error:

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at...**

I see the failure is happening on the OPTIONS pre-flight request. I've seen many StackOverflow posts about this kind of error, but none of the suggestions I've tried have worked.

Here is how my Node.js file is handling the requests:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require("path");
const cors = require('cors');

const e = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

    if('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});


...
```

I would think the code would return 200 on the OPTIONS method based on the code above but it still gets denied.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this CORS issue?

Comment: Perhaps also allowing the "OPTIONS" request instead of just GET and POST?

Comment: Why are you using the `cors` middleware and still defining your own cors response. Furthermore, you would have to add OPTIONS to the  `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header

Comment: @Dave Newton, I did have OPTIONS on the Access-Control-Allow-Methods, i.e. res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS') but didn't work when I had it under that. 


derpirscher, I added in the cors middleware later. I did not originally have cors middleware, but added it in as an attempt to see if it would fix the issue. Either way, it's still failing on OPTIONS.

Comment: So whats the result of the options request? Is the handler even executed at the server?